# how to add shipping method options

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I wrote a module with help of a [this link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method) and I don't know what to do if I want to show options for a shipping method,I mean I have one shipping(one carrier title) but different method names

is it related to creating other model? if so should I change my config.xml? or other file? I cvould not solve my problem I searched through internet a lot

```
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setPrice($price);
            $method->setCost($price);
            $result->append($method);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request.  If you have several methods, in the collectRates() method of the class that extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract you can create an array with method details. Then you can loop through the array:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/enabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    $methods = array('method_one'=>array('price'=>some_val,'title'=>some_title,'cost'=>some_cost)...add more methods);


        $finalMethods = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

       foreach($methods as $item){

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($carrierCode);
        $method->setMethod($item['code']);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($carrierTitle);
        $method->setMethodTitle($item['title']);
        $method->setPrice($item['price']);
        $method->setCost($item['cost']);
        $finalMethods->append($method);
    }

    return $finalMethods;
}
```

Also take a look at this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/ (there is a section called "Using Multiple Shipping Methods").

Comment: I don't have rate should I create a folder? I am totally a beginner at magento

Comment: Ok take a look at this article also : http://www.magentotricks.com/creating-a-customer-magento-shipping-method/. You have a rate model: $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/**rate**_result_method'), this line gives you a rate model.

Comment: yeah I found my rate folder thank you! great help!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: This will indeed show multiple options, but will assign same carrierCode.. and it will create multiple radio options with same id. When selecting any shipping option will keep the first option in selection always